# Decorate a python function to run a unit test when module is main

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I want to replace this boilerplate:

```py
def Foo():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_unit_test(Foo)
```

With this:

```py
@test_if_main
def Foo():
    pass
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# utils.py
import inspect

def test_if_main(f):
    caller = inspect.stack()[1]
    mod = inspect.getmodule(caller[0])
    if mod.__name__ == "__main__":
        print('running unit tests...')
    return f
```

```py
# Foo.py
from utils import test_if_main
@test_if_main
def Foo():
    print(42)

# handled by @test_if_main
# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     print("do unit tests here...")
```

```py
# Bar.py
from Foo import Foo

Foo()
```

- `python3 Foo.py` prints `do unit tests here...`
- `python3 Bar.py` prints `42`

Answer (score 0):

No, Because the `Foo` test function is defined without being called anywhere.
But you can try:

```
def test_if_main(test_func):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        run_unit_test(test_func)

@test_if_main
def Foo():
    pass
```

Comment: My unit test will call Foo. That's what I'm doing in the first example, passing Foo to the unit test, which will call it. What I would like to do is automatically (in the decorator) run the unit test when I do `python3 Foo.py`, but not run the unit tests if I do `import Foo` from another module.

Comment: The edit still requires typing `if __name__ == "__main__": ...` inside every module.